# How do I execute a shell script against my localstack Docker container after it loads?

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, dockerfile, localstack

I want to spin up a localstack docker container and run a file, create_bucket.sh, with the command

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://my-bucket
```

after the container starts.  I tried creating this Dockerfile

```
FROM: localstack/localstack:latest
COPY create_bucket.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT []
```

and a docker-compose.yml file that has

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment:
      ...
    ports:
      - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
    command: sh -c "/usr/local/bin/create_bucket.sh"
```

but when I run

```
docker-compose up
```

the container comes up, but the command isn't run.  How do I execute my command against the localstack container after container startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use mount volume instead of "command" to execute your script at startup container.

```
volumes:
      - ./create_bucket.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/create_bucket.sh
```

**Also as they specify in their [documentation](https://docs.localstack.cloud/get-started/#docker), localstack must be precisely configured to work with docker-compose.**

> Please note that there’s a few pitfalls when configuring your stack manually via docker-compose (e.g., required container name, Docker network, volume mounts, environment variables, etc.)

In your case I guess you are missing some volumes, container name and variables.

Here is an example of a docker-compose.yml found [here](https://www.bitovi.com/blog/running-aws-resources-on-localstack), which I have more or less adapted to your case

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    container_name: localstack-example
    hostname: localstack
    ports:
      - "4566-4583:4566-4583"
    environment:
      # Declare which aws services will be used in localstack
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEBUG=1
      # These variables are needed for localstack
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<region>
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<id>
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<access_key>
      - DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
    volumes:
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./create_bucket.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/create_bucket.sh
```

Other sources:

- [Running shell script against Localstack in docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563942/running-shell-script-against-localstack-in-docker-container)
- https://docs.localstack.cloud/localstack/configuration/

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same configuration, but I can't seem to execute the create-bucket.sh, I'm on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 with a docker-compose 3.4 version. Do you know something about OS platforms compatibility or any reported issues about that, please ? I'm completely out of resources on the net... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you exec into the container, the `create_bucket.sh` is not copied. I'm not sure why and I couldn't get it to work either.

However, I have a working solution if you're okay to have a startup script as your goal is to bring up the container and execute the creation of the bucket in a single command.

1. Assign a name to your container in `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack
    ports:
      - '4566-4583:4566-4583'
```

2. Update your `create_bucket.sh` to use [`awslocal`](https://github.com/localstack/awscli-local) instead, it is already available in the container. Using `aws` cli with an `endpoint-url` needs `aws configure` as a pre-req.

```bash
awslocal s3 mb s3://my-bucket
```

3. Finally, create a startup script that runs the list of commands to complete the initial setup.

```bash
docker-compose up -d
docker cp create_bucket.sh localstack:/usr/local/bin/
docker exec -it localstack sh -c "chmod +x /usr/local/bin/create_bucket.sh"
docker exec -it localstack sh -c "/usr/local/bin/create_bucket.sh"
```

4. Execute the startup script

```bash
sh startup.sh
```

---

To verify, if you now `exec` into the running container, the bucket would have been created.

```bash
docker exec -it localstack /bin/sh
awslocal s3 ls
```

[image: bucket created verification]

Answer (score 0):

Try by executing below

```
docker exec Container_ID Your_Command
```

Comment: I'm not understanding -- I shoudl run this instead of "docker-compose.yml"?

Comment: This way, once the container is up., you can run any missing commands against the container from the host

Comment: My goal is to bring up the container and execute the creation of the bucket in a single command, preferrably "docker-compose up," because that is a standard command that other developers will know.